# How do you add multiple system voltages to a design?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have been trying to search and been hitting a roadblock.

My system uses a 42V Li-Ion Battery in an E cycle. The controller I am designing uses the following voltages

3.3V/100mA for Logic and MicroController

10V-12V/5A for MOSFET PRE-Drivers, horn and lights.

Rest is all for the motor. 42V 15A Max

I am sure that Linear regulators are out. A buck topology is the one I need, but is there a system /chip that can be placed and can manage multiple voltages in one package?

Comment: There may be. You can peruse the selection charts that the manufacturers offer to find out, exactly. (I believe you will find some that may come close, though I'm not sure you will find any that are an exact fit for your needs.) If you find one or two, they will be very boutique parts.

Comment: Analog/LT and TI both make things like this. Maxim might as well.

Comment: My first cut at an architecture would be a buck converter to provide the 10 V-12 V @ 5 A, then a simple linear regulator off the 10 V-12 V rail to provide the 3.3 V @ 100 mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devices that include multiple switching controllers in one package are known as PMICs or multi-channel regulators. These are commonly used in microcontroller, microprocessor, or system-on-chip applications where many power rails are required. However, the input and output voltage ranges for these chips are generally lower than what you require. I personally have not seen any multi-channel switching converters or controllers that could accommodate those voltage ranges.

Your best bet is certainly to use a cascaded topology where your 42V battery feeds a high current 12V buck converter, which then feeds a small buck or LDO for your 3.3V supply. While this is not a single chip solution, it is likely as small of a solution as you can reasonably get.

For the 42V -> 12V Buck @ 15A you can choose between an integrated converter module with the FETs and passives built-in, or a controller where you will have to add the switches yourself and passives yourself. I have not seen a standalone converter that supports this voltage range.

[Example Converter Module](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vicor-corporation/PI3526-00-LGIZ/7319725)
[Example Controller](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc-maxim-integrated/MAX25208ATPA-VY/13907150)

As mentioned in the comments, for 3.3V @ 100mA there is little reason not to go with an LDO unless heat is a big problem. Either way, here are some options for either route:

[Buck Converter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc-maxim-integrated/MAX77596ETBB-T/5880838)
[Low Dropout Regulator](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/LP5907MFX-3-3-NOPB/3906441)